# How copy files from current docker container to another container

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I am building a docker container with a nodejs application, which will be build from meteorJS. For the build a **shell runner** is used (`meteor build /opt/project/build/core --directory) as this is all done in a gitlab CI.

```
build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - deploy
  before_script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - meteor npm install
    - meteor build /opt/project/build/core --directory
  script:
    - cd /opt/project/build/core/bundle
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
```

So the files of the application are now at `/opt/project/build/core`. Now I want to copy those file into another docker image (project-e2e:latest)

I tried to do

```
docker cp /opt/project/build/core/bundle project-e2e:latest/opt/project/build/core
```

But this gives me the error

```
Error response from daemon: No such container: project-e2e
```

But I see, the container is running:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                PORTS                                      NAMES
a238132e37a2        project-e2e:latest                       "/bin/bash"              14 hours ago        Up 14 hours                                                      clever_kirch
```

Maybe the problem is, that I'm trying to copy out of the shell runner docker image and the target project-e2e is 'outside'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the files generated into the container you can copy them by using docker:

`docker cp nightwatch:/opt/project/build/core/your_file <your_local_path>`

Basically the pattern is:

`docker cp <source> <target>`

If the source/target is a container, you have to use:

`<container_name>:<path_inside_container>`

Comment: source and target are swaped, aren't they?

Comment: You can use them in both ways.. depending where's the source/target.

Comment: It is not working. I've updated to post for better understanding.

Comment: The problem is that you didn't assign a name for your container, container's name != image's name, in this case, you should try with the container's ID.